# Customize Facebook Like Box With CSS Stopped Working

Tags: css, facebook-like

A few months ago, I had successfully customized a facebook like box. All of a sudden, it stopped working -- it is simply ignoring the css file. I'm hoping that someone can see what I'm doing wrong. Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("426348664054039");</script>
<fb:fan profile_id="106491872816751" stream="0" connections="10" width="300px" height="300px"
header="0" logobar="0"   css="myfile.css"></fb:fan>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of someone trying to help me fix my example, I'll settle for a link to *ONE WORKING EXAMPLE*!!! I am seeing one website after another explaining how to do this, and NOT ONE of them actually posts a working example -- only screenshots. Sheesh. Those who can't, teach? If I sound bitter, it's because I spent 4 hours on this months ago, and now, all of a sudden, poof, it just stopped working this week. And my other FB programming experiences have been similar: hours to do straightforward tasks, due to horrendous documentation, and then one day, poof! Stops working. I HATE FACEBOOK.

I hunted around some more, and it turns out that the CSS NO LONGER WORKS, since fb has changed some of their programming!! So that's 6 hours down the toilet. HATE is no longer a strong enough word to describe how I now feel about facebook.

SOLVED: Apparently, this feature stopped working around January 20, 2013. As of Feb. 6, 2013, it seems that facebook has corrected the problem, due to popular demand!

Comment: Did it stop working immediately after you made the change?

Comment: Where in my post did I say that I made any change? I made no change.

Comment: You don't need to add the word "EDIT" to your edits.  Everyone can see the complete edit history of your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14610874/revisions).

Comment: What a control freak. Please don't edit my posts. I like it with the word "EDIT". Does using it violate the TOS?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: working example is here on the red bull austria page (right sidebar): http://www.redbull.at/cs/Satellite/de_AT/Red-Bull-Austria/001242758636758

Comment: Thanks, but actually, working example no longer needed, as the problem which was the basis for my request was fixed by facebook over the past few days...

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has removed the option of embeding custom css into the likebox.

They have done this because of security implications, the main ticket in the issue tracker is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134065666769816

Here are two more tickets discussing it:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/551565398209379

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252607348205681/