# Facebook Like Box - Edit iFrame CSS

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, widget

I was able to edit the css to my iframed twitter widget using the following instruction:
[iframe CSS Override for New Twitter Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361823/iframe-css-override-for-new-twitter-widget)

However I can't seem to get something similar to that to work on the facebook like box widget.
Does any one know if something similar will work facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that Facebook has removed all methods of customising the like box. See:

- http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/how-to-style-a-facebook-like-box-with-css-30/ (the `update` box)
- [Customize Facebook Like Box With CSS Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610874/customize-facebook-like-box-with-css-stopped-working)
- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134065666769816
- http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/551565398209379
- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252607348205681/

Comment: I read most of those articles as well. I just heard the same thing about the twitter widget but then found a solution so I want to see if someone can get that same jQuery method to work with the Facebook widget.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my blog, you can see the Facebook likebox [here](http://heera.it/), just to change the Facebook look of the `iframe`, can't change the `css`, AFAIK

**CSS**

```
.sidebar-box {
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #DDD;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #DDD;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <iframe src="..." scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:258px;margin-left:-17px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

[**DEMO1**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TdfYD/1/) and [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TdfYD/3/).

Comment: I looking to be able to control more than just the border. I'm looking to edit the font color for all text and link and remove the avatar.

Answer (score 0):

View the source code of your likebox via developer tools in chrome or FF. Copy the iframe code and replace the likebox plugin code taken from facebook with the iframe code. You can then change iframe widths and heights etc.